# What does $\bar{\in}$ symbol mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, distribution-theory

I found in an old Russian math book the following symbol:

$\bar{\in}$ or $\overline{\in}$ used in the given context:

$\eta_\epsilon(x)=1, \ x\in A^\epsilon$

$\eta_\epsilon(x)=0, \ x\overline{\in}A^{3\epsilon}$

The context is that the function $\eta$ vanishes at the point $2\epsilon$ on the x axis , and exists between $0$ and $2\epsilon$.

The meaning of this should be something like $\not\in$, one would think, but in this case $ A^{3\epsilon}$ is already outside  the domain of $x$, so it would have sufficed to write

$\eta_\epsilon(x)=0, \ x\not\in A^{2\epsilon}$ .

So my guess is that the symbol $\overline{\in}$ means something  else.

Does anyone know what?

Thanks

Comment: Do both $\overline{\in}$ and $\notin$ appear in the book?

Comment: Never saw that symbol. But note that it is possible that you only require $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)=0$ to hold outside of $A^{3\epsilon}$, not outside of $A^{\epsilon}$. That's quiet common in analysis. Depends what $A^{\epsilon}$ is.

Comment: See Hausdorff's [Set Theory (original ed. 1937)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Set_Theory/TFA_EAAAQBAJ) page 12: $a \ \overline {\varepsilon} \ A$ for "$a$ is not an element of $A$". IMO the reason is only typographical.

Comment: Thanks Mauro Allegranza!

Comment: Weird. It looks like $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ but the equal sign should be beneath the symbol, not above.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is right.  An old way to write $\notin$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , I have got a feedback from my Russian professor. Apparently, this symbol does not mean $\not\in$, but that "belongs to the complement set".  To be accurate.

Comment: Ok, thanks: $x \in A^c \text { iff } x \notin A$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, all in that single symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see Hausdorff's [Set Theory](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Set_Theory/TFA_EAAAQBAJ?gbpv=1) (original German edition 1937), page 12:

> $a \ \bar \varepsilon \ A$ for "$a$ is not an element of $A$".

You can comapre it Compare with Bernays' [Axiomatic Set Theory (1958)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Axiomatic_Set_Theory/aHi4AAAAIAAJ), page 58: "the complement of $A$ is $\bar A = \{ x \mid x∉A \}$.

The use of "bar" for negation is due also to [Hilbert & Ackermann (1928)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic/45ZGMjV9vfcC), where the negation of proposition $X$ is denoted with $\bar X$.

Comment: Grazie, this is clarifying everything here. Thanks